# Why is WordPress adding closing tags to my <input> tag (a void element)?

Tags: html, wordpress

Assume for a minute I have a form on wordpress and in this form I have three hidden form fields like listed below...

```
<input name="One" type="hidden" value="1" />
<input name="Two" type="hidden" value="2" />    
<input name="Three" type="hidden" value="3" />
```

Now I hit save. When rendered in the source code in the browser I see them nested like this...

```
<input name="One" type="hidden" value="1">
   <input name="Two" type="hidden" value="2">
      <input name="Three" type="hidden" value="3">
      </input name="Three" type="hidden" value="3">
   </input name="Two" type="hidden" value="2">
</input name="One" type="hidden" value="1">
```

This page is setup as HTML 5 with a normal doctype  and renders like this on both latest chrome / firefox.

As you can see it is almost as if wordpress is not seeing these hidden input elements as stand alone. When I try to close them myself with an  tag it still rewrites it like this. I have never EVER seen anything like this, but I do know that wordpress has taken many liberties in the past of rewriting code it thinks is invalid.

Any ideas what might be going on here?

Comment: What version of wordpress are you using? What plug-ins are installed and active?  What theme are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that WordPress renders code as XHTML. Hence, a closing syntax is required on all elements (including a self-closing syntax on [void elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#void-elements)).

Here's some more info that may help you.
[How do I turn off self-closing tags for markup in WordPress (for HTML5, or HTML4, for example)?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1/how-do-i-turn-off-self-closing-tags-for-markup-in-wordpress-for-html5-or-html4)